# Text blurry when running nonuniversal iPhone app on iPad

Tags: interface-builder, retina

Basically I'm trying to [retinafy my game](http://struct.ca/2010/retinafy-your-game/)

So my application isn't universal, its specifically for the iPhone. I just would like to to also look its best when running on the iPad.

I've created a simple method to load the high resolution images when running on the iPad in scaled 2x mode. Which is working.

However my problem isn't the images. Its my UILabels and UIButtons. When I scale up the text becomes slightly blurry.

So they look fine with 1x scale. Its just 2x scale on the iPad.

Is there property I can set or a way I can redraw the UILabels/UIButtons so that they are more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an iPhone app is running on an iPad and scaled x2, you can't draw to each individual pixel. It is literally an enlarged 320x480 pixel screen (or 640x960 if you are using an iPad 3 which simulates an iPhone with a retina display).

Hope that helps.